# Laravel UpdateOrCreate method returns empty values

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables: books, editions, and listings.

I have one form where a user can select a book, then a book edition and all of the fields (title, author, year, publisher, edition year, etc.) fill in automatically. If the user selects "My book isn't on this list", then he has to fill in the fields himself. The fields related to the listings table have to be filled by the user himself in any case:

#### this is how the form looks like

[image]

I'm trying to use the Laravel UpdateOrCreate method on submit, so only the new information is added to the database:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
        Book::UpdateOrCreate([
            'id' => $request->get('id'),
         ],
         [
            'book_title'  => $request->get('book_title'),
            'book_author'  => $request->get('book_author'),
            'book_description'  => $request->get('book_description'),
            'book_year'  => $request->get('book_year'),
            'book_language'  => $request->get('book_language'),
        ]);
        Edition::UpdateOrCreate([
            'id' => $request->get('eid'),
         ],
         [
            'book_id' => $request->get('id'),
            'image_url'  => $request->get('image_url'),
            'publisher'  => $request->get('publisher'),
            'edition_year'  => $request->get('edition_year'),
            'pages'  => $request->get('pages'),
            'cover_type'  => $request->get('cover_type'),
        ]);

        $listing = new Listing();
        $listing->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
        $listing->edition_id = $request->get('eid');
        $listing->listing_description  = $request->get('listing_description');
        $listing->price  = $request->get('price');
        $listing->condition  = $request->get('condition');
        $listing->shipping_type  = $request->get('shipping_type');
        $listing->image_url  = $request->get('listing_image');
        $listing->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('new-listing')->with('message', 'Listing added succesfuly!');
    }
```

This is what automatically fills the input fields (just regular inputs with name attributes such as book_title, book_author and the rest that are in my UpdateOrCreate method above.

```html
<div class="row">
    <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "thriftyourbook-user";
        $password = "123";
        $dbname="thriftyourbook";
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
        $qu = "SELECT book_title,book_author,book_description,book_year,book_language,id FROM books ORDER BY book_title";
        $res = $conn->query($qu);
        $q = "SELECT e.image_url,e.publisher,e.edition_year,e.pages,e.cover_type,e.id,b.book_title FROM editions as e JOIN books as b ON e.book_id = b.id ORDER BY b.book_title";
        $re = $conn->query($q);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group col-6">
        
        <label for="book">{{ __('l.selectbook') }}</label>
        <select id="book" class="form-control" name="book" onchange="bookInfo()">
            <option value="no">{{ __('l.onthislist') }}</option>
            <?php
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
            { 
                echo "<option value=\"yes\" data-id=\"$r[5]\" data-ttl=\"$r[0]\" data-auth=\"$r[1]\" data-desc=\"$r[2]\" data-yr=\"$r[3]\" data-lang=\"$r[4]\"  value=\"$r[5]\"> $r[0] </option>";
            }
            ?> 
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6" id="edition-field-div">
        <label for="edition">{{ __('l.selectedition') }}</label>
        <select id="edition" class="form-control" onchange="editionInfo()">
            <option value="no">{{ __('l.editionnotlist') }}</option>
            <?php
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($re))
            { 
                echo "<option value=\"yes\" data-img=\"$r[0]\" data-pblshr=\"$r[1]\" data-eyr=\"$r[2]\" data-pg=\"$r[3]\" data-cov=\"$r[4]\" data-eid=\"$r[5]\" data-titl=\"$r[6]\" value=\"$r[5]\"> 
                $r[6] ($r[1], $r[2], $r[3] pages, ";
                if  ($r[4] == 'HC') {
                    echo "Hardcover) </option>";
                } elseif ($r[4] == 'PB') {
                    echo "Paperback) </option>";
                }   
            }
            ?> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

No errors are returned, but every time I submit the form, every field related to the books or editions table becomes empty. Only the listing information is filled correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: where is book::id() coming from in your post? You should probably pass the actual book id as the value for your select drop down.

Comment: @Yeak I noticed this problem too, and I solved it. Now I'm getting a different error, so I edited the original post.

Comment: Try removing $book->save(); and $edition->save(); i dont think its needed for updateorcreate function

Comment: @Yeak Did that. No errors now, but now every book and edition field is returned empty.

Comment: Sorry i can really tell but do you have input fields with their names as the ones your are trying to fill out such as image_url, book_title ... can you do a var_dump($request->all()) to see all the request values being sent in the post?

Comment: @Yeak Just did the var_dump, it only returns the request values for the listing information - nothing on books or editions.

Comment: Thats the problem - the values your trying to insert and update on the table do not exist in the request. Your view page is a bit confusing to me but you must ensure that each input element has a name with what you are trying to retrieve. Also if your using laravel why not use blade templating to generate the html its much cleaner and easier.

Comment: @Yeak I just removed .prop('disabled', true) to the input fields that have been automatically filled, and that fixed the problem. But this was necessary so the user can't edit any existing information. I'll look into removing the attributed upon submit. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Instead of disabled add readonly to the input (heres a reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: @Yeak Could you possibly know a fix for the error I get now? When I don't choose a book that's already in the database and add information for a new book to be created - `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'edition_id' cannot be null`.

Comment: you have a column called edition_id im not sure what that is suppose to be or what table its on but if its not a primary key then the column is set up to require a value and cannot be null if it is a primary key on edition table then you need to edit that column to either set it as a primary key where it auto increments or you need to assign a value to it when doing the update or insert - if you would like that column to be null just edit the column in mysql and allow it to be NULL or add default value of NULL